# How to create a 1D sparse tensors from given list of indices and values?

Tags: pytorch, sparse-matrix

I have a list of indices and values. I want to create a sparse tensor of size 30000 from this indices and values as follows.

```
indices = torch.LongTensor([1,3,4,6])
values = torch.FloatTensor([1,1,1,1])
```

So, I want to build a 30k dimensional sparse tensor in which the indices `[1,3,4,6]` are ones and the rest are zeros. How can I do that?

I want to store the sequences of such sparce tensors efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In general](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.sparse_coo_tensor) the `indices` tensor needs to have shape `(sparse_dim, nnz)` where `nnz` is the number of non-zero entries and `sparse_dim` is the number of dimensions for your sparse tensor.

In your case `nnz = 4` and `sparse_dim = 1` since your desired tensor is 1D. All we need to do to make your indices work is to insert a unitary dimension at the front of `indices` to make it shape `(1, 4)`.

```py
t = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(indices.unsqueeze(0), values, (30000,))
```

or equivalently

```py
t = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(indices.unsqueeze(0), values, (30000,))
```

Keep in mind only a [limited number of operations](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html) are supported on sparse tensors. To convert a tensor back to it's dense (inefficient) representation you can use the `to_dense` method

```
t_dense = t.to_dense()
```